# Merge multiple files using shell adding filename

Tags: windows, file, shell

I want to merge multiple files (`.svg` in my case) into one big file (about 1200 of files)

I do it (windows) by command `copy *.svg all.svg` that works cool, but I need to have filename before every part of content of file so I'll be able to perform some bulk text transforms

So my output now in all.svg is

```
<CONTENT OF 1.svg>
<CONTENT OF 2.svg>
```

etc.

I want it to be

```
1.svg
<CONTENT OF 1.svg>
2.svg
<CONTENT OF 2.svg>
```

etc.

Is it possible with shell or you know some tool to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a file named `concat.bat` that contains exactly this :

```
echo %1 >> all.svg
type %1 >> all.svg
```

and for ease of use, place it inside the directory containing all the .svg

Second, MAKE sure you deleted the previous "all.svg" before doing the following part

Third, open the command line, and type this in it:

```
for %n in (*.svg) DO concat.bat %n
```

and "voila", it will put all the *.svg into a (new) file named `all.svg`, and each part will be prefixed by its filename.

Comment: It should be possible to do this all in one file, either with an inline loop body or by `call`ing to a label.

Comment: True... i just copy pasted what i tried on the command line but indeed it could be inside the .bat